# Run keras.Models.fit() in graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

How to run keras.model.fit() in graph not with eager execution...??

I tried to run my model in graph by using tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution(), but the code return error: numpy must be run with eager execution

The error appear after checkpoint model

I’m using tensorflow GpU 2.1.0 and keras 2.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tensorflow2.x, `model.fit()` runs in graph mode by default, you can control this behavior by using the `run_eagerly` argument in the `model.compile(...)` method, which defaults to `False`.

Comment: owh so if i didn't use disable_eager_execution, model.fit() run in graph mode by default..??, but before i use graph mode i tried to run my code and i got error resource  does not exist, so i thought that my model didn't support eager execution

Comment: Yeah, behind the scenes Keras constructs the graph of the training step and runs it in graph mode by default, unless you ask it to run in eager mode.

Answer (score 0):

Even though eager mode is by default in `TF2.x`, under the hood `keras.model.fit()` run in graph mode for faster computation. If you want to use some advanced functionality of `TF2.x` and want to use graph mode as in `TF1.x`, then import tensorflow as follows

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

Mixing functionality of `TF1.x` and `TF2.x` by using `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` is not suggested. It could result in lot of issues down the line. Thanks!